# JavaFX Button released event

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `Button` that I want to assign a different action on release to the pressed action.  I did this in Swing before using `javax.swing.ButtonModel`  similar to this:

```
ChangeListener changeListnerUp = new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {

       AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) event.getSource();
       ButtonModel model = button.getModel();
       boolean pressed = model.isPressed();

       if (pressed) {
           System.out.println( "Up Button pressed, String: " + upString );
       } else
            System.out.println( "Up Button released, String: " + stopString );
       }
    }

};
```

Can anyone recommend a suitable alternative in JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch multiple events, but in this case there is already a property that is changed according to these events: The [`pressed` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pressedProperty) or alternatively the [`armed` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#armedProperty), if leaving the `Button` with the mouse should cause an event. Simply listen to changes of this property

Example:

The following code animates a `Circle` as long as the `Button` is pressed:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(300, 20, 5);
    Timeline animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(circle.centerYProperty(), circle.getCenterY())),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(circle.centerYProperty(), 300))
    );
    animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    animation.setAutoReverse(true);

    Button btn = new Button("Play");
    btn.pressedProperty().addListener((observable, wasPressed, pressed) -> {
        System.out.println("changed");
        if (pressed) {
            animation.play();
        } else {
            animation.pause();
        }
    });

    Pane root = new Pane(btn, circle);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a method from the node class that you can use, called [addEventFilters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-).

```
exampleNode.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,                
new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    public void handle(MouseEvent) {  
                    //do stuff here
                 };
              });
```

Comment: This seems to work well but i have a few glitches: every time i press the button the event multiplies.  eg: 1st press "Hello" 2nd press"Hello Hello" and so on. Also,  The first press on opening the application doesnt do anything.  It only responds from the second press of the button. Do you know what causes this?

Comment: What happens here if you use a finger gesture to press the button on a touchscreen?