# How to correctly implement the Action Listener to button

Tags: button, javafx, actionlistener, eventhandler

This program first displays a bullseye created by three different sized cirlces.
Once the animate me button (btn) is clicked, the function animation() will make the existing circles shrink inwards untill the size of the cirlces are zero. New circles will be created behind the preexisting circles which are shrinking towards zero. The new cirles will also shrink towards zero. This process will continue untill the user hits the animate me button again.

In this snippet, I have the process that creates the new buttons after the preexisting circles that are already on screen. After those NEW circles that have been created, the circles that HAVE already shrunk to zero will be reused to keep the cycle going:

```
public class Target extends Application 
{
    Circle[] cir = new Circle[7];
    Button btn = new Button("Animate me!");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    /** 
     * @param primaryStage will create the target and the start button first 
     *        displayed onscreen to the user 
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        root.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");      

        cir[0] = new Circle(400, 250, 200);
        cir[0].setFill(Color.RED);
        cir[0].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        cir[1] = new Circle(315, 165, 115);
        cir[1].setFill(Color.WHITE);
        cir[1].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        cir[2] = new Circle(230, 80, 30);
        cir[2].setFill(Color.RED);
        cir[2].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");

        root.getChildren().addAll(cir[0], cir[1], cir[2]);      
        root.getChildren().add(btn);      

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();

        btn.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            animation();
            btn.setText("Press to Stop");
        });
    }

    public void animation()
    {
        ScaleTransition[] st = new ScaleTransition[7];
        boolean recycleCircles = false;


        st[0]= new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), cir[0]);
        st[0].setToX(0.0f);
        st[0].setToY(0.0f);
        st[0].play();

        st[1] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(5.5), cir[1]);
        st[1].setToX(0.0f);
        st[1].setToY(0.0f);
        st[1].play();

        st[2] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(4), cir[2]);
        st[2].setToX(0.0f);
        st[2].setToY(0.0f);
        st[2].play();

       // int delayInc = 1;
        int delay = 1;

        //will create circles (will rotate between white and red) and then add 
        //to scaleTransitions
        while(btn.isPressed() == false)
        {
            for(int i = 3; i<st.length; i++)
            {     
                if(recycleCircles == true)
                {
                    i = 0;
                    recycleCircles = false;
                }
                if(i % 2 == 1)
                {
                    cir[i] = new Circle(400,250,200);
                    cir[i].setFill(Color.WHITE);
                    cir[i].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");
                    root.getChildren().add(cir[i]);
                    cir[i].toBack();

                    st[i] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), cir[i]);
                    st[i].setDelay(Duration.seconds(delay));
                    delay++;
                    st[i].setToX(0.0f);
                    st[i].setToY(0.0f);
                    st[i].play();

                }

                else if(i%2==0)
                {
                    cir[i] = new Circle(400, 250, 200);
                    cir[i].setFill(Color.RED);
                    cir[i].setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;");
                    root.getChildren().add(cir[i]);
                    cir[i].toBack();

                    st[i] = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(7), cir[i]);
                    st[i].setDelay(Duration.seconds(delay));
                    delay++;
                    st[i].setToX(0.0f);
                    st[i].setToY(0.0f);
                    st[i].play();

                }

                if(i == 6)
                    recycleCircles = true;
            }
        }

        btn.setOnMousePressed(event ->
        {



        });   

        btn.setOnMouseReleased(event -> 
        {
            for(int y = 0; y<st.length;y++)
            {

            }
        });


    }  
}
```

Comment: `while(btn.isPressed() == false)` -< is a no no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX Button released event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909578/javafx-button-released-event)

Comment: How are you drawing the circles what classes are you using?. I would suggest you use a sort of timer to loop the process of drawing the circles repeatedly. That is you might want to put the code in the action listener in some sort of looping timer and pause/play or do something else when the action button is clicked.

Comment: The program has been upgraded to give you a look into what I'm doing

Comment: Look at the link I posted. Your code should follow that answer very closely.

Comment: `codeexampleNode.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,                
new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    public void handle(MouseEvent) {  
                    //do stuff here
                 };
              });`        This is what your are referring to?